# Is there any model or theory which considers that spacetime and symmetries are all emergent?

Tags: spacetime, symmetry, models, emergent-properties

There are a lot of models which propose that spacetime is actually emergent. I am not sure if this necessarily means that all symmetries associated with spacetime would also be emergent.

Do you know about any model or theory which actually considers that spacetime and its symmetries are all emergent? Or even more, a model or a theory which proposes that spacetime and literally all symmetries in physics (global, gauge, local... and even Lorentz and CPT symmetries) are all actually emergent?

I am studying some models proposed by a few physicists (like E. Witten or H. B. Nielsen) which seem to propose what I am looking for, but I would like to know if there are any others

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726932/2451